# Get user's locations using Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there a way to get user photos locations using Instagram API? I've read the Instagram API doc, but I just found a [geography endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/geographies/) request, where you pass a `geo-id` and get the photos from this location.

Thanks!

Comment: Geo-coordinates will most likely be in EXIF data, which you can read with [book.exif](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php).

Answer (score 2):

You must have the latitude and the longitude to search for photos.
Have a look at [this](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search) ;)

Hope i helped.

Comment: "Sorry, this page isn't available."